# Slow Perforce fetch when nothing needs to be fetched

Tags: perforce

I apologize for my shallow knowledge of how Perforce works. I realize that I am diving into something beyond my grasp, but I'm hoping I can find some answers here.

I am experiencing very slow Perforce fetches from a remote server into a local server via `p4 fetch`.

I expect the fetch operation to be slow when there are lots of changes to be fetched. However, I notice that it takes the same ~40 minutes to fetch when the local server already has the latest revision.

Is Perforce downloading the entire remote depot for comparison?

Is there any way to have Perforce recognize only the changes it needs to fetch?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: That seems crazy slow. Even in my largest depot w/~200K files, several GB, takes maybe 8 minutes to fetch from scratch. But if there's nothing (or a few things) new? About 2-3 SECONDS. And that's on a slow server. The thing that has always made Perforce very fast is that it *doesn't* (by default) compare what you have in your workspace. Make sure your defined workspace includes only those areas you need. I suspect, though, that there might be something else going on here. Perforce Support could probably help you figure this one out. This is definitely not normal.

Comment: This seems very unlikely. Is it happening only on 1 host or all the hosts ? I suspect this to be outside perforce, like network issue? Is your file storage on NFS by any chance? That adds to slowness in Perforce.